# Counting consecutively based on more than one criteria in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

My data looks something like this

```
     order val1 val2 win
 1:     1  8.5  6.0  NA
 2:     2  7.0  5.0  NA
 3:     3  6.0  5.0  NA
 4:     4  6.0  5.0  NA
 5:     5  6.0  5.0  NA
 6:     6  8.0  7.0  NA
 7:     7  5.0  4.0  NA
 8:     8  5.0  4.0  NA
 9:     9  5.0  3.0  NA
10:    10  7.0  2.0  NA
11:    11  4.0  3.0  NA
12:    12  4.0  3.0  NA
13:    13  3.0  2.5  NA
14:    14  6.0  5.0  NA
15:    15  3.0  2.5   1
16:    16  2.0  1.0  NA
17:    17  5.0  3.5  NA
18:    18  3.0  2.7  NA
19:    19  2.5  1.7  NA
........ etc ..........
```

What i'm struggling with is to basically create a new column which starts counting after and only after `win==1`. Add on top of that `val1` has to be lower than `val2` of the previous row. And keeps counting as long as `val1` is lower than `val2`, if not it skips until that criteria holds up, until a total of seven times. Something like this:

```
     order val1 val2 win cond_win
14:    14  6.0  5.0  NA       NA
15:    15  3.0  2.5   1       NA
16:    16  2.0  1.0  NA        1
17:    17  5.0  3.5  NA       NA
18:    18  3.0  2.7  NA        2
19:    19  2.5  1.7  NA        3
20:    20  1.5  1.3  NA        4
21:    21  1.2  0.5   1        5
22:    22  6.0  5.5  NA       NA
23:    23  5.0  4.5  NA        6
24:    24  4.0  3.5  NA        7
25:    25  3.0  2.5  NA       NA
26:    26  2.0  1.5  NA       NA
```

Ater this i would like it to reset and basically start looking again.
Currently struggling with the skipping part.

---

The loop solution is the route i've tried to take, but it would also be too slow.

Are there any elegant solutions in `data.table` that might be faster?

This is some data, and what i've come up with so far.

```
DT <- data.table(order=seq(1,50,1),
             val1=c(8.5,7,6,6,6,8,5,5,5,7,4,4,3,6,3,2,5,3,2.5,1.5,1.2,6,5,4,3,2),
             val2=c(6,5,5,5,5,7,4,4,3,2,3,3,2.5,5,2.5,1,3.5,2.7,1.7,1.3,0.5,5.5,4.5,3.5,2.5,1.5),
             win=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1))

# find the first
DT[win==1 & val1 < shift(val2,1),cond_win:=1]

# attempt at looping
for(i in 1:7){
 DT[shift(cond_win,1)==i & val1 < shift(val2,1),cond_win:=i+1]
}
DT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has clearly stated that four conditions need to be fulfilled for counting a row

1. Start counting after and only after `win` == 1.
2. Count only rows where `val1` is lower than `val2` of the previous row.
3. Keep counting valid rows until seven is reached.
4. When seven is reached start over again.

Once counting has started, any intermediate appearances of `win` == 1 do *not* restart the count.

The difficulty here is the irregularity of the `win` == 1 and `val1`<sub>i</sub> < `val2`<sub>i-1</sub> patterns and the interdependence of the conditions. So, this problem can't be fully vectorized. We still need a loop over the appearances of `win`== 1:

```
# find all appearances of win == 1, remember row number of next row,
# ensure start is a valid row number (no overrun in case last row has win == 1)
start <- DT[win == 1 & order < .N, order + 1]

DT[, cond_val := val1 < shift(val2, fill = FALSE) ]
DT[order >= first(start), cond_win := cumsum(cond_val)]

# implied loop over all appearances of win == 1
dummy <- lapply(start, function(start) {
  if (DT[start, cond_win > 7]) {
    # restart count from this row
    DT[order >= start, cond_win := cumsum(cond_val)]
  }
})

# rows which don't satisfy the conditions become NA
DT[!cond_win %between% c(1,7) | !cond_val, cond_win := NA]
DT
```

The result looks as follows:

```
    order val1 val2 win cond_val cond_win
 1:     1  8.5  6.0  NA    FALSE       NA
 2:     2  7.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
 3:     3  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
 4:     4  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
 5:     5  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
 6:     6  8.0  7.0  NA    FALSE       NA
 7:     7  5.0  4.0  NA     TRUE       NA
 8:     8  5.0  4.0  NA    FALSE       NA
 9:     9  5.0  3.0  NA    FALSE       NA
10:    10  7.0  2.0  NA    FALSE       NA
11:    11  4.0  3.0  NA    FALSE       NA
12:    12  4.0  3.0  NA    FALSE       NA
13:    13  3.0  2.5  NA    FALSE       NA
14:    14  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
15:    15  3.0  2.5   1     TRUE       NA
16:    16  2.0  1.0  NA     TRUE        1
17:    17  5.0  3.5  NA    FALSE       NA
18:    18  3.0  2.7  NA     TRUE        2
19:    19  2.5  1.7  NA     TRUE        3
20:    20  1.5  1.3  NA     TRUE        4
21:    21  1.2  0.5   1     TRUE        5
22:    22  6.0  5.5  NA    FALSE       NA
23:    23  5.0  4.5  NA     TRUE        6
24:    24  4.0  3.5  NA     TRUE        7
25:    25  3.0  2.5  NA     TRUE       NA
26:    26  2.0  1.5  NA     TRUE       NA
27:    27  8.5  6.0  NA    FALSE       NA
28:    28  7.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
29:    29  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
30:    30  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
31:    31  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
32:    32  8.0  7.0  NA    FALSE       NA
33:    33  5.0  4.0   1     TRUE       NA
34:    34  5.0  4.0  NA    FALSE       NA
35:    35  5.0  3.0  NA    FALSE       NA
36:    36  7.0  2.0  NA    FALSE       NA
37:    37  4.0  3.0  NA    FALSE       NA
38:    38  4.0  3.0  NA    FALSE       NA
39:    39  3.0  2.5  NA    FALSE       NA
40:    40  6.0  5.0  NA    FALSE       NA
41:    41  3.0  2.5  NA     TRUE        1
42:    42  2.0  1.0  NA     TRUE        2
43:    43  5.0  3.5  NA    FALSE       NA
44:    44  3.0  2.7   1     TRUE        3
45:    45  2.5  1.7  NA     TRUE        4
46:    46  1.5  1.3  NA     TRUE        5
47:    47  1.2  0.5  NA     TRUE        6
48:    48  6.0  5.5  NA    FALSE       NA
49:    49  5.0  4.5  NA     TRUE        7
50:    50  4.0  3.5  NA     TRUE       NA
    order val1 val2 win cond_val cond_win
```

Comment: Thank you Uwe Block! Works perfectly. An elegant sollution, with a data.table framework! Really like the usage of the `function` as well as `.N` and `%between%` since these are areas i'm trying to improve and learn with data.table. Cheers :)

Comment: Your feedback is appreciated! I'm not sure if restart the count in row 41 is correct as the triggering `win`== 1 is several rows earlier in row 33.

Comment: It's absolutely correct and works with a larget dataset. Since the code recognizes 1 in row 33. Then `val1 < val2` is 41. And the `win==1` on row 44 is effectively ignored. As well as the win in row 21. :)

Comment: This question was really a tricky one. Took me quite some time and some headaches to find an approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
# data generation
exempleData <- data.frame(order = 1:50 ,val1 = runif(50),val2 = runif(50))
exempleData$win <- NA; exempleData$win[sample(1:50,1)] <- 1
exempleData$cond_win <- NA
# select rows under conditions and assign value one to cond_win
exempleData$cond_win[((which(exempleData$win == 1)+1):length(exempleData$val1))][
  exempleData$val2[((which(exempleData$win == 1)+1):length(exempleData$val2))-1]>
    exempleData$val1[((which(exempleData$win == 1)+1):length(exempleData$val1))]
  ] <- 1
# transform 1 to count in cond_win
exempleData$cond_win[!is.na(exempleData$cond_win) ] <- cumsum(exempleData$cond_win[!is.na(exempleData$cond_win) ]) 
# Remove count greater than 7 
exempleData$cond_win[exempleData$cond_win>7] <- NA
# Here we are!
exempleData
```

Comment: Thanks Damien for your response! It works in a data.frame setting which is excellent. But it lacks the last condition/concept, which is: After 7 counts i would like it to reset and basically start looking again. So look again for the next `win==1` and do the count to seven again and so forth. Since the data i'm working with is quite a few rows :) Thanks again for you post though, it was very helpful!

Comment: What happen when a win==1 and the count hasn't reach 7, for instance if 2 win==1 occurs in two adjacent rows? Do the count start again or do we ignore the win==1?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Damien! If for instance 2 `win==1` occurs in two adjacent rows we continue the count from the 1st `win==1`, i.e ignoring the adjacency.